# Servicestack return wrong content type when returning a file with html extension

Tags: servicestack

I am testing Servicestack Rest Files service.  When calling it from angularjs and asking for an html file back, the results comes back as the standard servicestack html format instead of the json format.  Even when appending ?format=json, it does not work correctly.  I am trying to browse for html files and are then trying to load it into ace editor.  I think Servicestack is getting confused with the response type.  I checked and the Content-Type is set to application/json on the client side when doing the request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the request you're making is:

```
GET /files/myfile.html
```

It's returing HTML because the `.html` file extension is a **built-in registered format** in ServiceStack so it assumes you're **explicitly** requesting the API in the **HTML** Format.

You can avoid this ambiguity by specifying the file `Path` on the QueryString, e.g:

```
GET /files?Path=myfile.html
```

Which tells ServiceStack to send it back using the most appropriate format as specified in the `Accept` header. Or if you prefer you can also explicitly specify the format by adding the `{.ext}` at the end of the path info, e.g:

```
GET /files.json?Path=myfile.html
```

Another option, if you're not using ServiceStack's built-in HTML support is to remove the HtmlFormat Plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.RemoveAll(x => x is HtmlFormat);
```

Whicih will make `.html` no longer a registered format so the `.html` extension will be benign.

> Note: removing HtmlFormat also removes built-in HTML functionality like its [auto HTML pages](http://docs.servicestack.net/html5reportformat)